# How to install iostat to Red Hat 5, without internet connection?

Tags: redhat, iostat

Title is pretty clear, I have a server which doesn't have an internet connection. So I can't use yum or anything like that. I want to download necessary files with my PC and upload to server via SSH and then install it.

But I don't know, where to download iostat and how to install it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iostat is part of the sysstat package.  You can download and install the sysstat RPM and you should get what you're looking for.

After downloading the package to your server, call "rpm -i package_name"

You should be able to get the sysstat RPM from the RedHat Network, but here's another link:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=sysstat

Comment: one way to get the file over is, download the rpm local to your computer. throw that on a usb stick, mount that up to your linux box. i think linux automounts these days but `cd /mnt; mkdir usb; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb;` can do the trick. then copy and run with John K's info.

Answer (score 3):

`iostat` is part of the `sysstat` package (`yum whatprovides "*/iostat"`).
You need to download the `sysstat` RPM package.

Where to download is a bit tricky, if I remember correctly the Red Hat repos are not publicly available.
If you have another Red Hat server (same version) with Internet, you can run `yumdownloader --destdir /tmp/ sysstat`.
That will download the package to /tmp.

Once you uploaded the RPM to your server, install it via `yum localinstall /tmp/sysstat.rpm`.